# Remove html entities from a databases

Tags: sql, html-entities

Due to errors of my predecessors a (MySQL) database I would like to use contains a lot of HTML entities (e.g. `&euro;` instead of `€`).

As the database should contain raw data (a database shouldn't have anything to do with HTML) I want to remove them from the DB and store it in proper UTF8, the collocation is already that.

What would be a good way to fix this? The only thing I can think of is to write a PHP script that gets all the data, runs it through html_entity_decode() and writes it back. It's doable since it's a one-time-operation and the DB is only about 100MB large, but it's still less than optimal.

Any ideas?

Comment: If it's only a few different characters, you could probably do an update query with simple string search/replace. But if it's a wide variety, then go with the PHP round-trip option.

Comment: There are over 50 entities in use in this database alone, and HTML allows for every character to be written as a HTML entity using the &#xxx; syntax, so it's not as simple as search & replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no-one could provide a satisfying SQL-only solution, I solved it with a script similar to this one.
Note that it only works if all the tables you use it on have a primary key, but this will usually be the case

```
<?php
// Specify which columns need to be de-entitiezed
$affected = array(
    'table1' => array('column1', 'column2'),
    'table2' => array('column1', 'column2'),
);

// Make database connection
$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=yourdb;host=yourhost", "user", "pass");

foreach($affected as $table => $columns){
    // Start a transaction for each table
    $db->beginTransaction();

    // Find the table primary key. PHP5.4 syntax!
    $pk = $db->query("SHOW INDEX FROM " . $table . " WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'")->fetch()[0];

    foreach($columns as $column){
        // Construct a prepared statement for this column
        $ps = $db->prepare("UPDATE " . $table . " SET " . $column . " . = ? WHERE " . $pk . " = ?");

        // Go through all rows
        foreach( $db->query("SELECT " . $column . ", " . $pk . " FROM " . $table) as $row){
            $row[0] = html_entity_decode($row[0]);  // Actual processing
            $ps->execute($row);
        }
    }

    // Everything went well for this table, commit
    $db->commit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tnink u need to create a mysql procedure. (with SELECT loop and update replace) 
 `REPLACE(TextString, '&apos;','"') ;`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database (Oracle, MySql, etc) and whether you can take it offline you might be able to export all the DDL and data as a large SQL script (containing INSERTs for all the tables).  Then you could do a standard search/replace using `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/&euro;/€/g' script.sql
```

then drop the database or truncate the tables and recreate it using the script.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I think you are going to have to resort to PHP at some stage, converting a lot of these entites in SQL is going to invole a huge amount of desicion logic.

However, One approach I can think of if you must use SQL, is to create a user defined function, that esentially has a huge case statement in (Or lots of if/then's) :

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html
```

Then you should simply be able to do something like:

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3,mtuserdecodefunction(column-with-entities-in) FROM mytable
```

Which should in theory return you a cleaned table.